# How can I use grep to view only part of BFGMiner which is being run in screen over ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh, screen, grep

Okay, bear with me on this. I'm using a program called BFGminer, which hopefully you know is a bitcoin mining program. Anyway. It updates every second a few lines that look like this:

```
DEVICE 0: xxxx
DEVICE 1: xxxx
```

This is just the basics of what I am concerned about. I need a way to view these few lines from a terminal window if possible. The only issue that I have is that I can not seem to get *grep* to update the pipe I have coming into it.

I have the command running on another machine, and that machine also has a screen with BFGminer running.

So to access BFGminer's window, I am running a script to

```
ssh user@192.1681.1.11 screen -R
```

This gets me to the screen, but I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to detach it so it will continue to run.

If I run

```
ssh user@192.1681.1.11 screen -R | grep "^ DEV"
```

I can view all devices connected. Good so far. However, it does not update every few seconds like I need it to...

EDITED: figured out what to do. See answer.

Comment: don't know if you can find help here. but if you cannot, mayby you could try here to: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is more about getting grep to update at a certain rate.
As far as I know, grep only runs the command once. It doesn't update its output if the program that has its output | to grep updates the same line with the current information.

If there is a command that showed you the temperature of parts in your computer, and updated the same line instead of making a new one, and you wanted to grab just part of its output, it would be the same thing as I am trying to do here.

Comment: I have no answer for this, but I guess the problem here is `less` not `grep`. Since you are piping the output to the `less` program every 2 seconds, you are not in fact updating its content. Check [this answer on Unix & Linux - Is there a way to dynamically refresh the less command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4361).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh user@192.1681.1.11 ./RPC.sh
```

RPC.sh contains:

```
cd /opt/bfgminer/
while : ; do clear && ./bfgminer-rpc && sleep 5; done;
```

Looks like: http://pastebin.com/wrTb18TL

Does a good enough job. It just doesn't have all the info I need. I'll make a new question later for trying to analyze the data if I can't figure it out.

Thanks everyone for the ideas :)

EXPLANATION:
turns out bfgminer has a RPC (Remote procedure call) feature. All you need to do is add a flag when you start bfgminer. "--enable-api"

I haven't figured out how to tidy up the output yet using grep. But at least this will update properly with some of the needed information.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail`, it will follow a file as it grows. You can pipe `tail` into `grep`: `tail changing-log-file | grep whatever-you-need`. You can have BFGminer produce a logfile you can tail with the -L parameter apparently, use `-L /path/to/file`. Then on your local system you can do something like:

```
ssh server.com tail -f /path/to/file | grep DEVwhatever
```

just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this process when you want to stop following the log.

Happy mining!